# What happened when Master Yoda went to find his Lightsaber crystal?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-legends

In the end of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 5 Episode 9 *A Necessary Bond*:

> **Kenobi:** Ahsoka, it's good to see you're all safe.
>   **Ahsoka:** Yes master. We had quite an eventful mission.
>   **Huyang:** The most eventful since Master Yoda went to find his lightsaber crystal.
>   **Younglings:** Whoa! What! Tell us what happened! What happened then?

**Me:** Yes.. yes.. Tell us what happened!

> **Kenobi:** I'm afraid that story will have to wait.

**Me:** Kenobi, you sucking backstory blocker!!! Anyway, I'll see it on SciFi.SE.

I wish they had told the story there, but I'm hoping it has been covered by EU. Does this story exist anywhere?

Comment: /yoda Found the crystal I did.  Herh herh herh.

Comment: Well, you see, there were these [noodles](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident)...

Comment: I WANT TO KNOW HECK IT

Answer (score 2):

The movies never show this, but the video game [Knights of the Old Republic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic) suggest that a more *traditional* Jedi apprenticeship (than the incomplete and rather extraordinary ones in the movies) simply includes finding the crystal for one's own hand-crafted lightsaber. Of course that was an even *longer* time ago than the long, long time ago the movies play, but I wouldn't be surprised if Huyang's comment merely hints at a non-standard way of Yoda finding his crystal - which is also what Wookieepedia suggest though I can't identify the source of this quote:

> [Yoda constructed this lightsaber as an apprentice under the instruction of the architect droid Huyang. It is possible Yoda did this onboard the Crucible after acquiring his crystal on Ilum.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_lightsaber)

So probably something interesting happened on [Ilum](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ilum), but there's no specific information on this.